# GPIO control of alternate function pin

Tags: arm, stm32

I have an **STM32F4discovery** and using a pin as SPI CLK. But I also want to be able to control the pin as GPIO to generate ANY frequency I want (STM32 only lets you prescale APB clock).

How can I simply use GPIO_Toggle() on that alternate pin?

Comment: Why do you need a specific frequency? Generally a slave SPI device would have a maximum rated clock, and you just need to make sure you're using a clock that's no higher than this. See @Majenko's comment to my answer, since indeed using my code precludes you from using the SPI peripheral, and I see no reason for you to do that.

Comment: I want to program spi memory, and want to do that on max freq. prescalling dosent give me max freq (40MHz)...

Comment: From the STM32F4xx datasheet, section 2.2.4: "SPI1 can communicate at up to 42 Mbits/s, SPI2 and SPI3 can communicate at up to 21 Mbit/s." If you're using SPI2 or SPI3, forget about it as it can't be done. If you're using SPI1, you could slightly overclock your device by using a 42 MHz clock. Here 42 MHz = 168 MHz/4, where 168 MHz is the STM32F4's default frequency. To avoid overclocking, another possibility is configuring the STM32F4's PLL for a 160 MHz core frequency, since 160 MHz/4 = 40 MHz, which would get the exact frequency you need.

Comment: By the way, disregard my answer below. You have no hope of bit-banging the SPI protocol at a frequency close to 40 MHz. Your best bet is doing what I suggested in the previous comment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @swineone, I didn't think of adjusting the frequency at 160MHz  .. cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinitialize the pin as a software controlled output. For instance, if you're using the STM32 Standard Peripheral Library, and assuming the pin in question is PA5, you'd have to do something along the lines of:

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

GPIO_StructInit(&GPIO_InitStructure);
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_5;
GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);
```

Possibly you'd also need to set the field `GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed` if your clock signal is faster than 2 MHz (the default setting).

From now on you can do `GPIO_Toggle(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_5)` and it would work, since the pin is now under software control. Of course, being under software control, the peripheral toggling the SPI clock would have no effect on the pin itself anymore. If you ever want to delegate control of the pin back to the peripheral, you'd run the code all over again, but set the field `GPIO_Mode` to `GPIO_Mode_AF`.

Comment: Note that doing this is exclusive of using SPI.  You can't use hardware SPI but with a manually toggled SCK signal - it just wouldn't work (how does the SPI system know what speed you're toggling the clock at?) so you would have to "bit bang" the whole SPI protocol if you wanted to do SPI with manual frequencies.

Comment: While probably not useful for the goal here, there's a chance one might actually be able to get the SPI engine to clock out data in accordance with the software toggled clock by telling it that it is an SPI slave, even though it is actually the master.  Software would have to manipulate the select line to the actual slave.